# does Flutter firebase auto paginate with stremBuilder?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-streambuilder

I am using Firestore snapshots as a stream builder and loading widgets with listwiew builder. will it auto-paginate? does Flutter Firebase auto paginate with StremBuilder?

```
class twatter extends StatefulWidget {
  const twatter({super.key});

  @override
  State<twatter> createState() => _twatterState();
}

class _twatterState extends State<twatter> {
  Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>? stream;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    stream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Apps')
        .doc('Twatter')
        .collection('userTweets')
        .orderBy('time', descending: false)
        .snapshots();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xff111218),
      // backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 17, 17, 17),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: stream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                cacheExtent: 9999,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final post = snapshot.data!.docs[index];

                  return tweet(
                    postID: post.id,
                    tweetStr: post['tweetStr'],
                    userID: post['userID'],
                    nickName: post['nickname'],
                    time: "${post['time']}",
                    likes:
                        '${post['agree'].length + post['mid'].length + post['disagree'].length}',
                    comments: '200',
                    retweets: '1k',
                    greenPercentage: post['agree'],
                    yellowPercentage: post['mid'],
                    redPercentage: post['disagree'],
                    postImageUrl: post['postImageUrl'],
                    profileImageUrl: post['profileImageUrl'],
                    isVerified: true,
                  );
                },
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}',
                      style:
                          TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontFamily: 'retro')),
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i tried a lot of pagination methords but what i want is for the stream to auto update while also paginating. how do i do that ?

Comment: "does Flutter firebase auto paginate with stremBuilder?" No it doesn't. But since I assume that is not very helpful to you, I recommend showing what you tried with the [pagination samples](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) from the documentation, and [where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

> Does Flutter Firebase auto-paginate with StreamBuilder?

As @FrankvanPuffelen mentioned in his comment, the simplest answer is no. Why? Because the [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) in Flutter is only a widget that builds itself based on the latest snapshot of interaction with a stream.

When you perform a query in Firestore, the `snapshot` object that is returned will contain **all** documents that satisfy the query. If you need to get the documents in smaller chunks, then you have to implement [pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) and load the data progressively.

Comment: Hey Sahil. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?